# Python-Eve: More than one additional lookup

Tags: python, eve

Using [additional lookups](http://python-eve.org/config.html#resource-item-endpoints) I am able to access a given document of a desired endpoint by a secondary one as stated in the docs:

> Besides the standard item endpoint which defaults to
>   `/<resource>/<ID_FIELD_value>`, you can optionally define a secondary,
>   read-only, endpoint like `/<resource>/<person_name>`. You do so by
>   defining a dictionary comprised of two items field and url. The former
>   is the name of the field used for the lookup. If the field type (as
>   defined in the resource schema) is a string, then you put a URL rule
>   in url. If it is an integer, then you just omit url, as it is
>   automatically handled. See the code snippet below for an usage example
>   of this feature.

So recalling the given example from the docs:

```
people = {
    # 'title' tag used in item links. Defaults to the resource title minus
    # the final, plural 's' (works fine in most cases but not for 'people')
    'item_title': 'person',

    # by default, the standard item entry point is defined as
    # '/people/<ObjectId>/'. We leave it untouched, and we also enable an
    # additional read-only entry point. This way consumers can also perform
    # GET requests at '/people/<lastname>'.
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field': 'lastname'
    },

    # We choose to override global cache-control directives for this resource.
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,

    # we only allow GET and POST at this resource endpoint.
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
}
```

Since `lastname` is set as a secondary endpoint I would be able to access the `people` endpoint either through the document id (which is default) or the `lastname` key of a stored document.

Assuming that each person has a unique `lastname` and a unique `nickname`. Is there a possibility to define more than one additional lookup in order to have access via the `lastname` and the `nickname`?

However, this example is just to show what I am looking for. In my real use case I have a database containing different product information and I want to be able to access those information by both the English and the German title so I can guarantee that all my additional lookups will result in unique document keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add more than one additional lookup to the same endpoint. What you can do however, is have multiple endpoints consuming the same datasource.

> Multiple API endpoints can target the same database collection. For example you can set both `/admins` and `/users` to read and write from the same people collection on the database.

Quote is from the [Advanced Datasource Patterns](http://python-eve.org/config.html#advanced-datasource-patterns). So you could simply have `/books/english/<title>` and `/books/german/<title>`. Both endpoints would still consume the same database collection.

Depending on your schema design you might also go the [Sub Resources](http://python-eve.org/features.html#subresources) path and set up  something like `/products/<language>/books/<title>`.