# can't search eve rest API - additional lookup not working

Tags: python, rest, eve

I was following the example here: https://github.com/pyeve/eve-demo/blob/master/settings.py

When I go to localhost:5000/apps, I can see all the documents in my collection, but when I search for an email at localhost:5000/apps/example@gmail.com, it says '404 not found'.

I've confirmed the regex, and the email addresses are in the documents. Can anyone see what might be wrong?

run.py

```
from eve import Eve


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Eve()
    app.run()
```

settings.py:

```
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']


MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017
MONGO_DBNAME = 'test_database'



apps = {
    'item_title' : 'app',

    'additional_lookup' : {
    'url' : 'regex("\b[\w.-]+?@\w+?\.\w+?\b")',
    'field' : 'developer_email',
    },

        'schema': {
            'address' : {
                'type' : 'string'
                },
            'developer_email' : {
                'type' : 'string',
                'minlength' : 1,
                'maxlength' : 15,
                'required' : True,
                'unique' : True,
            }
            }

DOMAIN = {
    'apps' : apps,
}
```

Comment: It seems you need to add a flask custom URL converter to make it understand the email format, but I don't know how to add this into a pyeve schema.

Answer (score 2):

In your settings.py you aren't doing the lookup correctly. It should be.

```
apps = {
    'item_title' : 'app',

    'additional_lookup' : {
    'url' : 'apps/regex("\b[\w.-]+?@\w+?\.\w+?\b")',
    'field' : 'developer_email',
    },

        'schema': {
            'address' : {
                'type' : 'string'
                },
            'developer_email' : {
                'type' : 'string',
                'minlength' : 1,
                'maxlength' : 15,
                'required' : True,
                'unique' : True,
            }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but when I tried that change, I saw the error: ValueError: malformed url rule: '/apps/<apps/regex("\x08[\\w.-]+?@\\w+?\\.\\w+?\x08"):developer_email>'

Answer (score 0):

You can't add more than one additional lookup to the same endpoint. What you can do however, is have multiple endpoints consuming the same datasource. By default standard item entry point is defined as /apps/'objectID'/. You will have to configure another endpoint to /apps/'new endpoint'.
[Python-Eve: More than one additional lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123375/python-eve-more-than-one-additional-lookup)

Answer (score 0):

@Vorticity pointed out a fix in a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306826/python-eve-rest-api-additional-lookup-not-working/58966051#58966051). Try the following:

```
'additional_lookup': {
    'url': 'regex("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$")',
    'field': 'developer_email'
}
```

You should be able to retrieve your item with or without url encoding eg:

```
localhost:5000/apps/example@gmail.com
localhost:5000/apps/example%40gmail.com
```

If you have any interest in making your items retrievable at the item level by email _only (not object id), you can use item_lookup_field together with item_url:

```
apps = {
    ...
    'item_url': 'regex("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$")',
    'item_lookup_field': 'developer_email'
}
```