# Python Eve - REST API additional_lookup not working

Tags: python, rest, flask, eve

I am facing the exact same issue that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838785/cant-search-eve-rest-api-additional-lookup-not-working). I have `user_creds` endpoint for my API. When I visit `localhost:5000/user_creds/`, I can see all the documents in that collection. But when I do something like `localhost:5000/user_creds/someemail@gmail.com`, I always get a 404 Not Found response.

`user_creds` domain in settings.py looks like this:

```
'user_creds': {
        'schema': { 
            'email': {
                'type': 'string',
                'regex': r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)",
                'required': True,
                'unique': True,
            },
            'password': {
                'type': 'string',
                'required': True
            },
        }

        'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],

        'item_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT'],

        'additional_lookup': {
            'url': 'regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$")',
            'field': 'email'
        }
    }
```

I am following the example given [here](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html#a-more-complex-application) but cant figure out where I am going wrong. Also, if I visit this URL: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/user_creds?email==%22abcd12@gmail.com%22`, I get all the documents in the collection instead of getting just a single document which matches the email regex. If I visit this `http://127.0.0.1:5000/user_creds?where=email==%22abcd12@gmail.com%22`, I am getting the desired response.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit late, but I'm just learning Eve.  Maybe this will help.  I think that if you remove the "^" from your regex definitions that you may get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vorticity has the right fix.  Just remove the leading "^" in your additional_lookup regex as follows:

```
'additional_lookup': {
    'url': 'regex("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$")',
    'field': 'email'
}
```

You should be able to retrieve your item with or without url encoding eg:

```
localhost:5000/user_creds/someemail@gmail.com
localhost:5000/user_creds/someemail%40gmail.com
```

If you have any interest in making your items retrievable at the item level by email *only* (not object id), you can use [item_lookup_field](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/config.html#resource-item-endpoints) together with [item_url](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/config.html#resource-item-endpoints):

```
'user_creds': {
    ...
    'item_url': 'regex("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$")',
    'item_lookup_field': 'email'
}
```